# how to sort struct elements with multiple conditions in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, struct

There are 3 given mushrooms named C, R and L, and every mushroom comes with different weigth. I would like to sort them by weight and by C being first R second and L last.
for example if this list is given:

```
L 6
R 8
C 9
L 7
C 8
C 9
R 9
L 10
```

then I would like the following output:

```
C 9
C 9
R 9
C 8
R 8
L 10
L 7
L 6
```

I have tried using the `sort()` funciton by sorting by R first, then sorting C and then sorting by weigth. This worked at first but I started to notice that this doesnt work with every input and that the problem is that every second `sort()` ignores the previous sort and then the letters/numbers go all over the place. I have only started learning how to program about 2 months ago so please try to answer with that in mind. Thank you all.

```
int sumShroom[3]{0, 0, 0};
int sumWeigth[3]{0, 0, 0};
struct shroom {
char name;
int weigth;

shroom(char _name, int _weigth)
{
    name = _name;
    weigth = _weigth;
}
};

vector<shroom> shrooms;
```

Comment: Show a minimal _complete_ example... "_I have tried using the `sort()` funciton_" Where? How? Show what you tried. Show also what wrong output results.

Comment: `std::stable_sort` if you want to sort twice, else make a comparator which does the dual compare for you.

Comment: `std::stable_sort` will not help if one is comparing one element then second element and second element happens to introduce different ordering. It will still need to take the previous ordering into account when writing sort comparator.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Won't it work if the stable sorts are done in 'reverse' order, from lowest to highest precedence field?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `std::sort` to an object that have comparision function.

The comparision function take 2 arguments and return `true` if 1st argument should come earlier than 2nd argument, `false` otherwise.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct shroom {
    char name;
    int weigth;

    shroom(char _name, int _weigth)
    {
        name = _name;
        weigth = _weigth;
    }
};

struct shroom_cmp {
    bool operator()(const shroom& a, const shroom& b) {
        // if name is C or R, it preceeds L
        if ((a.name == 'C' || a.name == 'R') && b.name == 'L') return true;
        if (a.name == 'L' && (b.name == 'C' || b.name == 'R')) return false;
        // if both name is L, compare weigth
        if (a.name == 'L' && b.name == 'L') {
            return a.weigth > b.weigth;
        } else {
            // compare weigth first
            if (a.weigth != b.weigth) {
                return a.weigth > b.weigth;
            } else {
                // have same weigth, compare name
                return a.name == 'C' && b.name == 'R';
            }
        }
    }
};

int main(void) {
    std::vector<shroom> shrooms = {
        {'L', 6},
        {'R', 8},
        {'C', 9},
        {'L', 7},
        {'C', 8},
        {'C', 9},
        {'R', 9},
        {'L', 10}
    };

    // sort it
    std::sort(shrooms.begin(), shrooms.end(), shroom_cmp());

    // print the result
    for (const auto& s : shrooms) {
        std::cout << s.name << ' ' << s.weigth << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```